# How to generate random numbers where user refresh the page in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

Hi I am creating a chat bot using react.My code is:

```
export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
     random : '',
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    addResponseMessage('Welcome to React Bot! Type start');
     return this.setState({random :  Math.floor(Math.random()*10000)});
  }
   handleNewUserMessage = (newMessage) => {
     fetch('http://localhost:5005/webhooks/rest/webhook', {
            method: 'POST',
             headers : new Headers(),
             body:JSON.stringify({"sender":this.state.random, "message": newMessage}),
             }).then((res) => res.json())
             .then((data) => {
              var first = data[0];
              var mm= first.text;
              var i;
              console.log(mm)
              toggleMsgLoader();
              setTimeout(() => {
              toggleMsgLoader();
            if (data.length < 1) {
              addResponseMessage("I could not get....");
            }
           else{
               addResponceMessage(mm)
           }
        }
    }

  handleQuickButtonClicked = (e) => {
  addUserMessage(e);
   this.handleNewUserMessage(e);
    setQuickButtons([]);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <Widget
        title="Rasa Sample Bot"
        subtitle="Asistente virtual"
        senderPlaceHolder="Type here ..."
        handleNewUserMessage={this.handleNewUserMessage}
        handleQuickButtonClicked={this.handleQuickButtonClicked}
        badge={1}
      />

    );
  }
}
```

When user give to messages to my bot.It will call handleNewUsermMessage() and execute and give responses to user.  `body:JSON.stringify({"sender":this.state.random, "message": newMessage}),` this code for when user refreshing the page that sender id will be change. But here every message it will create a random Id. I don't want every message. Whenever user refresh the page then only i want create random id.

How to solve this. Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, you can set the `state.random` inside the constructor.

Comment: Thank you @Ardweaden .It's working

Answer (score 0):

Define in your state

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      random: Math.floor(Math.random()*100),
    }
  }


  handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({random: this.min + (Math.random() * (this.max - this.min))});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>
        {this.state.random}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In react when you refresh the browser the components remounts. So to generate random number on refresh you should call the random number generating function in `componentDidMount()` lifecycle method. The below code will work.

```
class Button extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      random: null,
    }
  }

  min = 1;
  max = 100;

  generateRandom =()=>{
    this.setState({random: this.min + (Math.random() * (this.max 
     this.min))
  }});

  componentDidMount(){
    this.generateRandom();
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.generateRandom();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>
        {this.state.random}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this write in componentDidMount.

```
class Button extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          random : '',
        }
      }
    componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({random :  Math.floor(Math.random()*100)});
    }

      handleClick = () => {
        this.setState({random: this.min + (Math.random() * (this.max - this.min))});
      };

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click me</button>
            {this.state.random}
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.state = {
          random: Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
}`

Just Update the above line in the constructor and it will all work just fine